# dumping get_account_authorization_details in json format

Tags: ruby, json, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

using the AWS Ruby SDK v2
trying to get `IAM/account_autorization_details`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/IAM/Client.html#get_account_authorization_details-instance_method

Everything works as expected, but I would like to get the output in json format (sort of how the awscli dumps it: like `aws iam get-account-authorization-details`)

I'm not interested in exploring the results manually. I need to store the json for later audit purposes. Cannot use the awscli and I am doing multiple things (calling multiple services + logic in between) through the SDK and the result needs to be self contained.

Comment: I am not ruby-ist and I think you'll have better chance with putting a sample of your result and ask for a good way to translate in ruby. but what if you add .to_json to the response ?

Comment: yeah. thought about that but due to it's sensitive nature I cannot do that. Tried doing to_json on both the response and on the page from the response. it's not playing nice :(